# Using Reactive to sum the certain sections of Observable

Tags: reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am trying to use reactive operators to find individual sum of the values emitted by the observable. The end goal is to emit individual sums. The sequence looks something like this. The ones I want to add up are occuring as continuous groups (of varying length) with varying frequency in between the values I want to discard. The ones I want to add have a field which is of type bool and has value true.

```
-(F,2)-(T,4)-(T,2)-(T,7)-(F,8)-(F,9)-(F,1)-(T,2)-(T,1)-(F,1)-
```

What have I tried so far:

```
myObservable.
    .Where(x => x.IsItUseful == true)
    .Aggregate(0.0, (sum,currentItem) => sum + currentItem.Value)
    .Subscribe("NotYet")
```

This one give back the sum of ALL elements which have been marked as true.

```
myObservable
    .SkipWhile(x => x.IsItUseful == false)
    .TakeWhile(x => x.IsItUseful == true)
    .Aggregate(0.0, (sum, currentItem) => sum + currentItem.Item3)
    .Subscribe("NotYetAgain");
```

This one gives the sum of the first group only.

Right now I am trying along these lines.

```
myObservable
    .Buffer(myObservable.DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.IsItUseful => true)
    .Subscribe("NotSure")
```

I am still hazy on on BufferBoundary and BufferClosingSelector. I think a new buffer will open once I process a group of valid values. And this new buffer will have values from that point on wards till the end of another valid group. This means that I will pick up some not valid values too before the second group. I haven't been able to find some examples on Buffer with both open and close options getting used. Not sure if this is right approach too.

The final option is that I write an extension method on Buffer and put my custom logic there. But if there is an out of box solution I will prefer that.

Comment: Given the input sequence you mention above (I assume T-7 is a typo), what output would you expect to see? And do you want a running output or just an output after the sequence is completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two primary approaches I would recommend here. One uses `Scan`, the other uses `Buffer`/`Window`. Both of them have edge case problems that are solvable, but need clarity on the problem side.

Here's the `Scan` solution:

```
var result = source
    .Scan((0, true), (state, value) => (value.IsItUseful ? state.Item1 + value.Value : 0, value.IsItUseful))
    .Publish(_tuples => 
        _tuples.Zip(_tuples.Skip(1), (oldTuple, newTuple) => (oldTuple, newTuple))
    )
    .Where(t => t.oldTuple.Item2 == true && t.newTuple.Item2 == false)
    .Select(t => t.oldTuple.Item1);
```

`Scan` is similar to `Aggregate`, just more useful: `Aggregate` will only dump out one value at the end; whereas `Scan` emits intermediate values. So we track the running sum in there, resetting to 0 when we see a false. The next step (Zip) combines the latest message with its predecessor, so we can figure out whether or not we have to emit: We want to emit if the new flag value is false, but the old flag value is true. We then emit the old sum.

There's an edge case problem here if the last flag value is true: I'm assuming you want to emit on the `OnCompleted`, but that won't currently happen. Please clarify if that's needed.

Here's the `Window` solution:

```
var result2 = source
    .Publish(_values => _values
        .Window(_values.Select(v => v.IsItUseful).DistinctUntilChanged().Where(b => b == false))
    )
    .SelectMany(o => o.Where(a => a.IsItUseful).Sum(a => a.Value));
```

Window by the distinctly new falses, then sum them, similar to what you proposed.

The edge case problem here is that you end up with a leading and tailing 0 if you begin/end with falses (as your sample set does). Removing those would require some clean up as well.

FYI: `Window` and `Buffer` are practically the same: They have the same overloads and each group values into "windows". `Window` returns them as an observable stream, and `Buffer` holds them into a list which returns when the window closes. For more [look here](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html#SequencesOfCoincidence).

---

Here's runner code if anybody else wants to test this:

```
public class Message
{
    public Message(bool b, int v)
    {
        IsItUseful = b;
        Value = v;
    }

    public bool IsItUseful { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

var values = new List<Message>
{
    new Message(false, 2),
    new Message(true, 4),
    new Message(true, 2),
    new Message(true, 7),
    new Message(false, 8),
    new Message(false, 9),
    new Message(false, 1),
    new Message(true, 2),
    new Message(true, 1),
    new Message(false, 1),
};

var source = values.ToObservable();

var result = source
    .Scan((0, true), (state, value) => (value.IsItUseful ? state.Item1 + value.Value : 0, value.IsItUseful))
    .Publish(_tuples => 
        _tuples.Zip(_tuples.Skip(1), (oldTuple, newTuple) => (oldTuple, newTuple))
    )
    .Where(t => t.oldTuple.Item2 == true && t.newTuple.Item2 == false)
    .Select(t => t.oldTuple.Item1);

var result2 = source
    .Publish(_values => _values
        .Buffer(_values.Select(v => v.IsItUseful).DistinctUntilChanged().Where(b => b == false))
    )
    .Select(o => o.Where(a => a.IsItUseful).Sum(a => a.Value));

result.Dump();  //Linqpad
result2.Dump(); //Linqpad
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed reply. Give me sometime to get my head around the code. Maybe you can replace  t.oldTuple.Item2  in first solution with  t.Item1.Item2 so that latest version of C# is not needed.
Also there is no guarantee about the starting and the ending values. If the sequence starts or ends with some elements marked true then I would ideally like to add and emit values, does not matter if it is an incomplete sequence.

Comment: Second solution seems to be emitting the sum of the individual sequences marked with False too. I am still checking it to make sure I understood what you said.

Comment: Using your sample set, I got (13,3) with the first solution and (0,13,3,0) with the second. Excluding the zeros, which stem from the mentioned edge cases, is that what you expect to see?

Comment: Yeah. That is what I wanted. Accepted the answer. Wish it was not so complicated though. Can you point me to some resources where they discuss how to deal with situations like this? Are there any clean ways to handle state in Reactive? Here essentially it boiled down to knowing when to stop and start taking values depending on what the previous emitted value contained.

Comment: State in Rx generally boils down to using `Scan`. I created some functions that wrap around it that you may find helpful. See https://gist.github.com/ShlomoAbraham/1b6e8dc1c7e00fc59f48fc690f4375cf. Generally http://introtorx.com/ is a great site, but there isn't much about state management there.